# Is there a way to write logarithm as a function of the inverse of $\cos$?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

How can I prove that

$\begin{equation*}
    \log x=2i\cdot \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)
\end{equation*}$

Any reference?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your real question?

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos\left(\frac{\log x}{2i}\right)=\frac{e^{\log x/2}+e^{-\log x/2}}2=\frac{x+1}{2\sqrt x}.$$

Comment: (+1) for however long this question remains undeleted

Comment: @robjohn: indeed :-) I know that the question is underspecified, but I found this formula so inexpected !